# Error 1004 for range based cell copy

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked through countless examples (and there are many to be found) of how to use Ranges to accomplish a VBA user defined function/sub to copy the value of one specified cell to another. Unfortunately, no matter which I try, I am unable to avoid Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error. Here is the very simple test code:

```
Private Sub Foobar()
On Error GoTo fooErrorHandler
Dim c1 As Range
Dim c2 As Range
Set c1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2")
Set c2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
c2.Value = c1.Value
Exit Sub
fooErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine _
                              & "Description:    " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help/pointers!

Comment: Is the `Sheet1` protected? Also, please `Dim c1 as Range, c2 As Range`, although that shouldn't cause the error, it is better to declare your variables correctly.

Comment: The macro code itself is valid, the problem might reside in the data. Please post some examples from the worksheet.

Comment: Sheet1 is not protected that I am aware of. Vanilla basic worksheet. I separated c1, c2 Dim statements as you suggested. No change in result though. btw I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: Not sure how to post a snippet of the spreadsheet... but by way of explanation this is a very sparse spreadsheet for my test purposes. Column 'D' has values 1 in row 1, 2 in row 2, 3 in row 3, 4 in row 4, 5 in row 5. Column B has 5 in row 3. Finally, in C1 I have "=barfoo()" which is function comprised of a single statement "call foobar." The VBA code for barfoo and foobar resides in Module1 for my spreadsheet.

Comment: I've updated my post to also show the error handler and the recent Dim statement change as suggested. Stepping through the code with the debugger, as soon as the statement "c2.Value = c1.Value" is executed, we go straight to the error handler and the message box displays the error 1004 with the text "Application-defined or object-defined error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you cannot use a `Function` to manipulate the worksheet object. It looks like you're trying to get around that by invoking a `subroutine` from the `barfoo` function call. I suspect that is the error... If you run the subroutine `foobar` manually (press F5 or run from the macro menu) it should execute without error.

I confirm that this implementation raises the error, and also test the manual call to `foobar` without error.

If you can better describe the ultimate goal, perhaps we can recommend a more reliable way to achieve it.

Comment: Fantastic! I was unaware of the restriction that Functions may not manipulate worksheet objects. I've confirmed that manually running foobar is successful. Thanks so much for that explanation!

Comment: Now... to your question about what I am trying to do... I have a fairly large spreadsheet which has a small percentage of user-entered data and a fairly large percentage of automatically entered data... so far all based on functions. These functions depend on other cell references to then lookup or calculate various values. What I am trying to do here is... *if* a certain value is found, then literally change a particular cell value to "conform" to requirements. I was doing that with a function, but I see now I must do that with a sub. But now I am not sure how to trigger that sub.

Comment: There are several `Event` procedures you could probably use to trigger that procedure. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Comment: Cheers. If this has helped you or solved your problem, [do consider upvoting or "accepting" the answer(s) which are helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I tried that, but as a new member I do not have sufficient reputation to upvote. I'll do this when I am able. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to *accept* an answer if it is satisfactory :)   (you would not be able to upvote until you have 15 rep, though).

Comment: Ahhh. OK. I have accepted the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying cells inside UDF (a function, that is used inside a cell the same way as built-in formulas) is not allowed. If you remove a call to `barfoo` from `C1` cell, both `Foobar` and `barfoo` should work without problems.