# I can't write a value into a worksheet cell (error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to write a value to a worksheet cell, but I only get a 1004 error.

I have tried various solutions and the answer is always this: error 1004.

How to resolve this?

```
Public Function test(a, b As Integer) As Integer
    test = a * b
    Call WriteCell(test)
End Function

Public Sub WriteCell(a As Integer)
    On Error GoTo myerr
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TestCell As Range
    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    Set TestCell = ws.Range("A1")
    TestCell.Value = "Test" & a
    
    Exit Sub
    
    myerr:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Stop
    
End Sub
```

To see the result of the writing test written in cell A1

Comment: Where do you get the error? What values are you passing when calling `test`?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565480/error-1004-for-range-based-cell-copy?rq=2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call this function in a sheet (as UDF) you should use a code:

```
Public Function test(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
    test = a * b
End Function
```

In the cell `A1` you should enter, e.g.:
`=test(3, 5)`

Or you can call this as a macro (my version of `test` function):

```
Sub MyMacro()
   WriteCell test(3, 5)
End Sub
```

Comment: 0


thanks for your quick response. I tried your code and obviously it works. In summary

you cannot modify the data of one or more cells directly from the "function"
you need to create a "sub" or rather a "macro" to modify, through the RANGE and CELLS functions, the cell data of a worksheet Thanks Dario